# Regarding Notification Sound In Android

Tags: android, notifications

In this question,actually i want to change the notification sound.For this i create a custom sound dialog box through which i can change and set the different ringtones.But the problem is that this sound dialog box is present in different activity i.e. SoundActivity while i write the notification code in different activity.Can you please tell me how can i use this sound activity in notification code so that by changing the ringtones,notification sound alos get changed. I have this sound activity in which i set the ringtones according to my demand.But i want these ringtones to be beep when notifications come.I write the code for notifictaion in another activity.Can you please tell me how can i use this sound activity,so that changes made in this activity changes the notification sound???

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            try
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.sound);
                setTitle("Sounds");
                initUpdateView();
                isSystemRingtone=PreferencesClass.getSystemRingtoneStatus(getApplicationContext());
                textviewRingtone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_ringtone_settings);
                if(PreferencesClass.getRingtone(getApplicationContext()).substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("/")){
                    String[] son=PreferencesClass.getRingtone(getApplicationContext()).split("/");
                    String[] s=son[son.length-1].split("\\.ogg");
                    String rep=s[0].replace("_", " ");
                    if(rep.startsWith("S ")){
                        rep=rep.substring(2);
                    }
                    textviewRingtone.setText(UppercaseFirstLetters(rep));
                    mysong=son[son.length-1];
                    mysongPath=PreferencesClass.getRingtone(getApplicationContext());
                    if(mysongPath.contains("system")){
                        SelectedTone="Sounds";
                    }
                    else{
                        SelectedTone="My Music";
                    }
                }
                songURI=PreferencesClass.getUri(getApplicationContext());


                LinearLayout layoutRingtone = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_ringtone_settings);
                layoutRingtone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showDialog(RINGTONE_DIALOG_ID);
                    }
                });

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR",ex.toString());
            }
        }

        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
        {       
            switch(id)
            {


            case RINGTONE_DIALOG_ID:
            {

                int selectedIndex = 1;

                //if(SelectedTone.equalsIgnoreCase("My Music"))
                    //if(SelectedTone.equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
                //  selectedIndex=0;
                Dialog dialog=null;
                //final String[] ringArray=new String[]{"My Music","Sounds"};
                final String[] ringArray=new String[]{"Sounds"};
                if(ringArray.length>0){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SoundActivity.this);
                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(ringArray, selectedIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    

                            if(which==0){
                                isSystemRingtone=1;
                                SelectedTone="Sounds";
                                PreferencesClass.setSystemRingtoneStatus(1, getApplicationContext());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Sounds");
                                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
                                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, false);

                                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                                String uri = songURI;
                                Log.d("uri", uri);
                                //chooses and keeps the selected item as a uri
                                if ( uri != null ) {
                                    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Uri.parse( uri ));
                                } else {
                                    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri)null);
                                }
                                startActivityForResult(intent,999);
                            }

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setTitle("Ringtone");
                    //dialog=new Dialog(SettingsGroup.group, R.style.Theme_D1dialog);
                    dialog=builder.create();
                    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                    return dialog;
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data is available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }           

            }
            return super.onCreateDialog(id); 
        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.d("req", requestCode+"");
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == RQS_OPEN_AUDIO_MP3) {
                    audioFileUri = data.getData();
                    Log.d("uri", audioFileUri.toString());
                    String son[]=audioFileUri.toString().split("/");
                    int k=0;
                    int id=1;
                    try{
                        id=Integer.parseInt(son[son.length-1]);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        k=1;
                        mysong=son[son.length-1];
                        mysongPath=audioFileUri.getPath();
                    }
                    //Log.d("id", son[son.length-1]);
                    if(k==0){
                        Uri allaudiosong = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        String audioID = data.getDataString();
                        Uri MyUri = Uri.parse(audioID);
                        String audioselection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=0 ";
                        Cursor cursor;
                        cursor = managedQuery(MyUri, STAR, null, null, null);
                        int i=0;
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {
                                    String song_name = cursor
                                            .getString(cursor
                                                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Song Name= "+song_name);
                                    //  mysong[i]=song_name;
                                    int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Song ID= "+song_id);
                                    if(id==song_id){
                                        mysong=song_name;
                                        if(SelectedTone.equalsIgnoreCase("My Music")){
                                            textviewRingtone.setText(mysong);
                                        }

                                    }
                                    String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Song FullPath= "+fullpath);
                                    if(id==song_id){
                                        mysongPath=fullpath;
                                        Log.d("path", fullpath);
                                        if(SelectedTone.equalsIgnoreCase("My Music"))
                                            PreferencesClass.setRingtone(mysongPath, SoundActivity.this);
                                    }
                                    String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Album Name= "+album_name);

                                    int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Album Id= "+album_id);
                                    Log.d("Audio Album Id= ",""+album_id);
                                    String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Artist Name= "+artist_name);

                                    int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
                                    System.out.println("Audio Artist ID= "+artist_id);
                                    i++;
                                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                            }
                        }



                    } 
                    Log.d("audio",audioFileUri.getPath());

                }
                if(requestCode==999){
                    Log.d("req", requestCode+"");
                    Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
                    try
                    {

                        Uri audioFileUri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

                        Log.d("uri", audioFileUri.toString());
                        String son[]=audioFileUri.toString().split("/");
                        int k=0;
                        int id=1;
                        try{
                            id=Integer.parseInt(son[son.length-1]);
                            Log.d("id", id+"");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            k=1;

                        }
                        Log.d("K", k+"");
                        if(k==0){
                            Uri allaudiosong = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                            Uri MyUri = uri;
                            PreferencesClass.setUri(MyUri.toString(), getApplicationContext());
                            songURI=MyUri.toString();
                            String audioselection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=0 ";
                            Cursor cursor;
                            cursor = managedQuery(MyUri, STAR,null, null, null);
                            int i=0;
                            if (cursor != null) {
                                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                    do {
                                        String song_name = cursor
                                                .getString(cursor
                                                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Song Name= "+song_name);
                                        //  mysong[i]=song_name;
                                        int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Song ID= "+song_id);
                                        if(id==song_id){
                                            mysong=song_name;
                                            if(SelectedTone.equalsIgnoreCase("Sounds")){
                                                String[] s=mysong.split("\\.");
                                                String rep=s[0].replace("_", " ");
                                                if(rep.startsWith("S ")){
                                                    rep=rep.substring(2);
                                                }
                                                textviewRingtone.setText(UppercaseFirstLetters(rep));
                                            }
                                        }
                                        String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Song FullPath= "+fullpath);
                                        if(id==song_id){
                                            Log.d("Done", "Done");
                                            //mysongPath=fullpath.substring(4, fullpath.length());
                                            mysongPath=fullpath;
                                            Log.d("path", fullpath);
                                            if(SelectedTone.equalsIgnoreCase("Sounds"))
                                                PreferencesClass.setRingtone(mysongPath, SoundActivity.this);
                                        }
                                        String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Album Name= "+album_name);

                                        int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Album Id= "+album_id);
                                        Log.d("Audio Album Id= ",""+album_id);
                                        String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Artist Name= "+artist_name);

                                        int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));
                                        System.out.println("Audio Artist ID= "+artist_id);
                                        i++;
                                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception localException)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }  


        }



        public void playSample(String s){
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;

            Log.d("RingtoneSelected",PreferencesClass.getRingtone(getApplicationContext()));
            if(!(s.substring(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase("/"))){
                try {
                    if(s==null){
                        afd = getAssets().openFd(PreferencesClass.getRingtone(getApplicationContext())+".mp3");
                    }else{
                        afd = getAssets().openFd(s+".mp3");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                if(s.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("/")){
                    player.setDataSource(s);
                }   
                else
                    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                player.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            float volume=(float)Float.valueOf(PreferencesClass.getVolume(getApplicationContext()));
            player.setVolume(volume,volume);
            if(!(s.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("/"))){
                player.setLooping(true);
            }
            else
                player.setLooping(false);

            player.start();
            playing=true;

            if(!(s.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("/"))){
                Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {


                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(10000);
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }
                        player.stop();

                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        public static String UppercaseFirstLetters(String str) 
        {
            char[] chars = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                if (!found && Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
                    chars[i] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[i]);
                    found = true;
                } else if (Character.isWhitespace(chars[i]) || chars[i]=='.' || chars[i]=='\'') { // You can add other chars here
                    found = false;
                }
            }
            return String.valueOf(chars);
        }

    I have this sound activity in which i set the ringtones according to my demand.But i want these ringtones to be beep when notifications come.I write the code for notifictaion in another activity.Can you please tell me how can i use this sound activity,so that changes made in this activity changes the notification sound??


    This is my notifcation code in which code for changing the sound has to be included.Actually in this code in notification code,i have used the mobile ringtone.But i want to use the sound from custom dialog box:

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeTabActivity.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, Utils.notiMsg, pendingIntent);
     notification.flags|=notification.FLAG_INSISTENT|notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
     //notification.vibrate=new long[] {100L, 100L, 200L, 500L};
     notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
     Utils.notificationReceived=true;
     Uri  uri  = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)!=0){
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
     This is the following code which contains notification class as well as sound activity.
```

Answer (score 0):

When do you launch your notifications from that class? On some event or...?

You can make a Service class that is used to dispatch the notifications, and whenever the user changes the notification sound you alert your Service to change the sound that will be used next time..

Comment: Actually on some event i get a notifications.Can you please tell me how to write as i am new to android.

Comment: Here is a an example of sending notifications from a service : http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/start-service-to-send-notification.html

Comment: And of course read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html  Its good to know, it will explain a few things to you about services and it can help you in your future development projects..

Comment: Hey can i take the ringtone in uri and parse it?